# How check all my deployments in Kubernetes are finished

Tags: kubernetes

I have several deployments that consist on my application. I would like to perform an custom action on the end of successful deployment of my app, this equal all deployments went well. How can I determine all my kubernetes deployments finished successfully?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with a basic `watch` command on all deployments ?

```sh
watch kubectl get deployments
```

And check the **READY** column.

Or am I missing the point here ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly clear what do You mean.

As pointed by [@Marc ABOUCHACRA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11506391/marc-abouchacra), you can use `watch`. This can be done in more k8s way by using `-w` flag like so `kubectl get deployments -w`.

But this only provides the information about the state Desired/Current/Up-to-date/Available.

```
$ kubectl get deployments
NAME      DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
nginx-1   1         1         1            1           27h
```

You might [Define Readiness probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/#define-readiness-probes).

> Sometimes, applications are temporarily unable to serve traffic. For example, an application might need to load large data or configuration files during startup, or depend on external services after startup. In such cases, you don’t want to kill the application, but you don’t want to send it requests either. Kubernetes provides readiness probes to detect and mitigate these situations. A pod with containers reporting that they are not ready does not receive traffic through Kubernetes Services.
>
> **Note:**  Readiness probes runs on the container during its whole lifecycle.

```
readinessProbe:
  exec:
    command:
    - cat
    - /tmp/healthy
  initialDelaySeconds: 5
  periodSeconds: 5
```

Or just use [Deployment status](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#deployment-status),

> A Deployment enters various states during its lifecycle. It can be  [progressing](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#progressing-deployment)  while rolling out a new ReplicaSet, it can be  [complete](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#complete-deployment), or it can  [fail to progress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#failed-deployment).

```
$ kubectl rollout status deployment nginx-1
deployment "nginx-1" successfully rolled out
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the deployments are in the same namespace you can run something like this:

```
 #!/bin/bash
    

check_unavailable() {
  deployments=$(kubectl get deploy -n "${NAMESPACE}" -o=jsonpath="{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{'\t'}{.status.unavailableReplicas}{'\n'}{end}")
  while read -r line; do lines+=("$line"); done <<<"$deployments"
  for line in "${lines[@]}"
  do
    read -ra arr <<< "$line"
    if [ "${arr[1]}" ]; then
      echo "${arr[0]} deployment has ${arr[1]} unavailable Replicas "

    fi
  done
}

check_unavailable
```

This should also work with deployments that have multi-container pods.

Answer (score 0):

The cluster I work with runs several applications, and each can deploy independently, so checking for *any* unavailable/in progress deployments doesn't work.

Our approach assumes some things about the release process:

- We avoid race conditions

  - We run our application releases with a CI/CD tool. The tooling reserves the environment for the application (multiple applications can deploy at the same time, but a single application won't have mulitple simultaneous deployments).
  - Each application "owns" their own resources (releases of different applications will not make changes to the same resource).
- The K8S pods have readiness probes/health checks configured that only mark deployments "good" when they are running correctly.
- The `spec.progressDeadlineSeconds` is set appropriately for each `Deployment` in the release

Taking an example of an application release with a web service worker, and a background worker, our deployment script might look like this:

```
#/bin/bash

# Cause deployment script to exit immediately if there is any failure, presumably in the `wait` commands
set -e

# This could be any action that generates kubernetes deployment(s)
kubectl apply -k "$DEPLOYMENT_DIR"

# Monitor the status of the web service worker
kubectl rollout status deployment.apps/app1-service &
_service=$!
# Monitor the status of the background worker deployment
kubectl rollout status deployment.apps/app1-background &
_background=$!

# Wait for all deployments to complete (or any of them to fail)
wait $_service
wait $_background

echo "Deployment complete"
```

The `rollout status` checks and corresponding `wait` actions should match the `Deployment`s/`DaemonSet`s/etc to be monitored as part of a release.